# Connect Codeigniter 3 with MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to connect Codeigniter 3 with Microsoft SQL Server 2008

But I'm getting error **Server error 500**.

I'm attaching code of database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=(local);Database=my_db;',
'hostname' => '(local)',
'port'     => '',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'database' => '',
'dbdriver' => 'odbc', // or mssql or sqlsrv
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
//'autoinit' => TRUE,
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
 );
```

I tried to connect simple core php file with MS SQL and it is connect successfully.

Following is the core PHP file code.

```
<?php
// Replace the value of these variables with your own data
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$server = "(local)";
$database = 'h2g2';

// No changes needed from now on
$connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database"; 
$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection established.";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO hg_users (u_uuid,u_name, u_email,u_new_email,u_password,u_display_name,u_forgot_token,u_forgot_token_request_time,u_verify_token,u_verified,u_last_login_date,u_last_login_ip,u_created_date,u_modified_date,u_status) 
                        VALUES ('1231233', '123123123 sdfsdfdsdf','ASsASas','asdasd','asd','ewrt','fgh','sdfgsasd','asdasd','2','zx','ZXcZX','aSzxCASD','ASDzxzx','1');";

    $result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
    die;

} else{
    die("Connection could not be established.");
}
?>
```

I'm using PHP 5.6 and Sql server 2008 with Xampp, Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: "*.. I'm trying to connect PHP script with MS Sql Server 2008.*". So, where is your code. We can't assume your code. We are not going to sit & watch that video. And, "*..Still same error I'm getting.*". What Error ??

Comment: Yes it's possible, trust me!

Comment: have you considered to learn php first?

Comment: @NanaPartykar

See this line on question before comment :
_Following is the core PHP file code._

Comment: @SnakeFoot

I already know about PHP.
See my question first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have successfully connected to the MS SQL server using CodeIginiter you do not need the second connection in part 2 of your code. Just call `$this->db->query("INSERT INTO ....")` That is all. CI does the rest for you. (remove `odbc_connect` and `odbc_exec`) and use the built in CI database class.

Your Code would look like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hg_users (u_uuid,u_name, u_email,u_new_email,u_password,u_display_name,u_forgot_token,u_forgot_token_request_time,u_verify_token,u_verified,u_last_login_date,u_last_login_ip,u_created_date,u_modified_date,u_status) 
        VALUES ('1231233', '123123123 sdfsdfdsdf','ASsASas','asdasd','asd','ewrt','fgh','sdfgsasd','asdasd','2','zx','ZXcZX','aSzxCASD','ASDzxzx','1');";

// runs the query to your MS SQL connection (automatically)
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Reference:

https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/examples.html